# Route to a server on subnet

Tags: router, routing, subnet

I have a version quantum router which has a subnet of `168.168.1.0/24`. My gateway is `192.168.1.1`.

I have another router for my network lab. This router is connected to the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet. The WAN ip address for my network Lab router is `192.168.1.238`.

The subnet `192.168.2.0/24` works great and I can access the internet. The lab router is also issuing dhcp address on the subnet.

The only issue is that my verizon router isn't routing traffic to the subnet. For example, suppose I have a server on `192.168.2.7`; how to route traffic to the `192.168.2.7`?

**Edit**

I have added an entry in the routing table. Not sure if I need to do anything else:

[image: Routing Entry]

Comment: Did you actually _add_ a route to that subnet? Not an exact duplicate but I just answered https://superuser.com/q/1246232/1686 a week ago...

Comment: @grawity I updated my post to show the route table entry - thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all I needed to do was add the routing table entry and on the router in the subnet, add a port forward entry.